# Building HTML table with nested cells and rows

Tags: html, pdf, html-table

I'm struggling to build the following HTML structure, I tried using `<div>` but I have a feeling that using `<table>` is the best fit here.

```
    div1    div2            div 3         div4
    9.57%  30.85%          40.43%        19.15%
     __________________________________________
    |   |  CONTROL  |                  |       |
    |   |___________|    DESCRIPTION   |   B   |
    |   | OPTIONAL 1|                  |   A   |
    | C |___________|__________________|   R   |
    | O |           | UNITS |OPTIONAL 4|       |  @c_height
    | D |   IMAGE   |  PER  |__________|   C   |
    | E |           | CARDS |OPTIONAL 5|   O   |
    |   |___________|_______|__________|   D   |
    |   | OPTIONAL 2|  OPTIONAL 3      |   E   |
    |___|___________|__________________|_______|
                  @c_width
```

When using `<div>` came to the following fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h2tea4nj/31/ but the nested cells are tricking me.

The idea here is to create a HTML template for a PDF file that will contain a lot of product labels to be impressed.

Would appreciate any help to solve this. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to handle this is to use a table.
To have nested cells, you can create tables inside tables.

As shown in the exemple bellow, you can achieve the effect you're looking for using this method.
For the fixed width, you can simply use css styling

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%;">
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 9.57%;">Code</td>
    <td style="width: 30.85%;">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Control</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Optional 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
          <td>Image</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Optional 2</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    
    <td style="width: 40.43%;">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Description</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td>Units per card</td>
                <td>
                  <table>
                    <tr>
                      <td>Optional 4</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>Optional 5</td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Optional 3</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    
    
    
    <td style="19.15%;">Bar code</td>
  </tr>
  <tr></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That's what I was looking for.